# Dividing a non-convex set into convex sets

Tags: general-topology, optimization, convex-geometry

Let $\Gamma$ be a non convex set in $R^2$. I would like to know which is the fastest algorithm to divide  $\Gamma$ in the minimum number of disjoint convex sets: 
$$min \;N$$
subject to:
$$\Gamma=\underset{i=1,...,N}{\cup}V_i$$

$$V_j\cap V_k=\emptyset\;\;\;\forall j \ne k $$
$$V_i \:\:convex \:\:set \;\; \forall i=1,...,N$$

EDIT:
Assume that $\Gamma$ is a rectangle with piecewise linear "holes" (see 
[this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxx8Q.png))

It's also fine if the implementation doesn't get the optimal solution, but a near one: The idea is to solve several path-planning convex optimization problems in real-time (I'm using Gurobi) in each set $V_i$. The smaller N the better, but the more time it takes to compute the sets, the worse.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Without more information about $\Gamma$ I think this is much too vague a question. If it's a polygon then perhaps there's a chance for a solution. How near is "near"? Have you researched the number of subsets you are looking for, and just asking about how to find them? The best you can hope for is an algorithm- no one here will write code. As for speed, what you want is a good algorithm. How fast it actually works will depend on the language and the input.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is not a polygon, how are you even going to represent it for purposes of your algorithm?

Comment: Q×R divides into infinitely many disjoint convex sets.  Can C handle this big stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Can C handle infinitely many holes? @Lab

Comment: Does the dividing the non-convex set into convex sets have to be done real-time, or can it be done in advance?  If real-time, have you considered the strong possibility that determining the division is more difficult the solving the original optimization problem over the non-convex region?

Comment: Everything has to be done in real-time. Yes, I've considered that possibility. I'd like to compare both approaches (solving the problem in the non-convex region, and solving several problems in convex, small regions)

Comment: The number of holes is finite in my problem